# Is there a reference to Muslims, Parsis and Christians in Hindu scripture?

Tags: puranas, history, other-religions

Wiki says :

> "the first ship bearing Muslim travellers was seen on the Indian coast as early as 630 CE. H.G. Rawlinson in his book Ancient and Medieval History of India[21] claims that the first Arab Muslims settled on the Indian coast in the last part of the 7th century CE. (Zainuddin Makhdoom II "Tuhafat Ul Mujahideen" is also a reliable work.)[22] This fact is corroborated by J. Sturrock in his Madras District Manuals[23] and by Haridas Bhattacharya in Cultural Heritage of India"

Many scholars see Christian influence in the theology of some sects.  Parsis came some time between 8 and 10 A.D.. So there is opportunity for all three religions to be mentioned in Puranic works.

Comment: The Bhavishya Purana contains prophecies of Christians and Muslim, although some of those may be interpolations.  I'm not sure whether any scriptures mention Zoroastrians.

Comment: Well, there is mention of "gathas" in atharva Veda, they are said as being one of the Hindu scriptures coming into being at the end of dwapara Yuga, I have a feeling they are the same gathas of zoroaster.

Comment: Atharva Veda 15.6.10–12:

sa brhatim disam anu vyacalat tam itihasas ca puranam ca gathas ca itihasasya ca sa vai puranasya ca gathanam ca narasamsinam ca priyam dhama bhavati ya evam veda

"He approached the brhati meter, and thus the Itihasas, Puranas, Gathas and Narasamsis became favorable to him. One who knows this verily becomes the beloved abode of the Itihasas, Puranas, Gathas and Narasamsis."